# How to convert http links to relative links to local files

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf tool to generate pdf files from htmls.

Html links are exported fine, but some of the linked resources are temporary links (expiring after 30 minutes), so I need to download them during the pdf generation. I tried to convert the http links to local links, but this didn't work.

I tired to change

```
  http://remote_server/Linked%20file.pdf
```

to

```
  file://relative_path/Linked%20file.pdf
```

Error: Unable to open external link.

I'm sure the the desired file is in relative_path/

It works when I use absolute paths,

```
   file:///home/user/relative_path/Linked%20file.pdf
```

but these files will be part of a zip, so I can't know where the user will extract them (so because of that I cant use absolute paths).

**Edit:**
The link is the following

```
 file://attachments/2ce8a9c9a41a4e7f94e8b57c13974020/93/original/Doc 3 Exhibit 2 Business Plan.pdf
```

the error is

```
  Error when getting information for file '/2ce8a9c9a41a4e7f94e8b57c13974020/93/original/Doc 3 Exhibit 2 Business Plan.pdf': No such file or directory)
```

Which means that when I click on a link, it tries to find the file in the root directory, not in the relative path. When I move the file in the root folder in /2ce8a9c9a41a4e7f94e8b57c13974020/93/original/Doc 3 Exhibit 2 Business Plan.pdf the linking works and the file opens.

Comment: Did you download `Linked%20file.pdf` to  `relative_path` folder? Relatively linked files do work in wkhtmltopdf if you link them properly.

Comment: Would love to know if this ever got answered – we are dealing with the same issue and have not figured it out yet.

Comment: I would strongly suspect `'/2ce8a9c9a41a4e7f94e8b57c13974020/93/original/Doc 3 Exhibit 2 Business Plan.pdf'` as failing because of the embedded space characters (prob. illegal in URLs). Use `+` instead, or, better still, get rid of spaces from file names altogether.